# Does anyone know this function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions, fast-fourier-transform

While experimenting with FFT phase errors, I found this function.
Can anyone explain what the mathematical definition is?
My guess is that it is somehow related to a sinc function.

[image: Function Plot]

Comment: When you wrote "sinc function", did you mean "sine function"?

Comment: Note that the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is *even* while this function appears *odd*.

Comment: This appears odd, true. I found that the imaginary part of the Hilbert transform of the sinc function looks similar on the first glance that is why I wrote it. Additionally, since it comes from the phase error of an FFT with a rectangular window, sinc function might play a role.

Comment: I don't understand how you actually generated this function but regardless, it looks similar to $\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x}$ up to scaling.